# Python Parse error: Too many columns specified

Tags: python, pandas

I am running Python through conda and my terminal. I was given a script that should be able to run without error. The script imports a url and reads it as a csv. This is what I have been given:

```
url = 'https://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/hurdat/hurdat2.html'
data, storm, stormList = readHURDAT2(url)
columnnames= ['list out each of the 20 column names']
```

The error begins with the next line:

```
for line in pd.read_csv(url, header=None, names=columnnames, chunksize=1):
```

The computer runs several iterations before outputting this error message:

```
Too many columns specified: expected 20 and found 1
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]: the code producing the error and the ***full*** error traceback

Answer (score 0):

> columnnames= ['list out each of the 20 column names']**

Do you literally have the string "list out each of the 20 column names" in your code? Im guessing youll have to replace that with the list of column names:

```
['a','b','c',etc]
```

Comment: What you have listed is correct.  I just didn't type out all column names